# Поиск и замена по регулярному выражению первых прописных букв в LibreOfficeCalc

Tags: регулярные-выражения, libre-office-calc

Необходимо ячейку с некоторым перечнем наименований разделенных точкой с запятой преобразовать в ячейку с этим же перечнем наименований где каждое наименование пишется с большой буквы. Пример текста в ячейке "Имя1; имя2" преобразовать в "Имя1; Имя2". Я подумал что поиск по регулярному выражению ; [а-я]\ выход, но он ищет в том числе и большие буквы и не учитывает первую букву в строке перед которой нет пробела. И что писать в строке замены тоже не понятно.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Вот такая UDF решила для меня этот вопрос.

```
Public Function UCASE_1(ByRef rng As Range)
    Dim arr, n As Integer
    arr = Split(rng, ";")
    For n = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) 'In arr
        arr(n) = Replace(Trim(arr(n)), Left(Trim(arr(n)), 1), UCase(Left(Trim(arr(n)), 1)), 1, 1)
    Next
    UCASE_1 = Join(arr, "; ")
End Function
```